# How to reset broken JavaScript Array Object from new iframe?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype-chain

I have a script which runs in a site that I cannot count on its `window.Array` object to not have been overridden. (It might have been changed by another script that was loaded before).

I create a new iframe and I would like to set the `window.Array` object back to the native Array prototype

```
    // let's assume Array.prototype.filter function was changed by another script
    Array.prototype.filter = ()=>{return "haha!"}

    console.log('test overridden: ', new Array(1,2,3).filter(x=>x));
    console.log('test overridden literal:', [1,2,3].filter(x=>x));

    // prints test overridden: haha
    // prints test overridden literal: haha

    // get new window with native code from iframe
    var iframe = null;
    (iframe = document.createElement('iframe')).name = 'native_function';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    var native = window.frames['native_function'];

    // here I am trying to set my broken Array to a new fresh copy
    Object.setPrototypeOf(Array, native.Array.prototype);

    console.log('test restored filter: ', new Array(1,2,3).filter(x=>x));
    console.log('test restored literal array filter', [1,2,3].filter(x=>x));

 
    // prints test restored filter: haha
    // prints test restored literal array filter: haha

    // It didn't work.
```

How can I restore my window.Array to the native.window.Array ?

**Note**
I want to restore the entire Array object to the original Array in the iframe window. Not only the filter function which I just used as as example.

Comment: I'm not sure if *anything* would work, but copying `native.Array.prototype.filter` back to `Array.prototype.filter`, or even `native.Array` to `Array`, might work better.

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf` does not do what you meant. You'd be looking for `Array = native.Array` or `Array.prototype = native.Array.protype` (both of which don't work, a new `[]` will still have the old prototype) or actually `Array.prototype.filter = native.Array.prototype.filter` to fix the overwritten function.

Comment: Why does your script even care if `Array` was overwritten or not? If the user did something like that, it's their fault not your script's. Notice that your script can't count on `window.frames` or `document.createElement` not to have been overwritten either.

Comment: @Bergi If it worked I wouldn't have asked the question. I'm trying to get it to work and I don't know how. I care about it because I want my script to work even if Array was corrupted by another script. That is what I want to solve.

Comment: "*I want my script to work even if Array was corrupted by another script.*" - but the other script might have corrupted so much more than just `Array`… In general it is not possible to restore a working environment from an untrusted/unreliable one, and it's rarely worth the effort to harden a script. If you really have a strong (security-sensitive) business need, the measures to take are a) make sure not to run untrusted scripts that cause havoc b) make sure your scripts run before them, so that they can save the original value c) use something like https://developers.google.com/caja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to restore the entire Array object to the original Array in the iframe window

You cannot overwrite the builtin array prototype that's used when creating arrays from literals, so instead you need to overwrite the methods on that one.

```
const iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"));
const iframeArray = iframe.contentWindow.Array;
document.body.removeChild(iframe);

const nativeArrayProto = Object.getPrototypeOf([]);
for (const p of ["constructor", "filter", "map", "slice", /* … */])
    nativeArrayProto[p] = iframeArray.prototype[p];
Array = nativeArrayProto.constructor;
Array.prototype = nativeArrayProto;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked.
Just change the iteration to :  ["constructor", "filter", "map", "slice"].forEach((p)=> {
            nativeArrayProto[p] = iframeArray.prototype[p];
        });
and I'll accept it as the right answer.

Comment: @Yaron Ooops, I meant to use `for … of`. Btw, depending on the level of paranoia, one would not want to rely on either of `Array.prototype.forEach` nor `Array.prototype[Symbol.iterator]` for the restoration of array prototype methods :-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree :) keep it safe

Comment: You could also write `const iframe, iframeArray;` instead of `const iframe; const iframeArray;`

Comment: @Bharata One could, but it's rather unusual and has no real benefit (especially if the two initialisers are on separate lines anyway).